# A proper function for nonlinear regression with 3 predictors

Tags: nonlinear-regression, computational-statistics, excel, predictor, minitab

There are three independent variables in my experimental work, namely flow rate (0.5 ≤ Q ≤ 9 where ΔQ = 0.5), particle size (a = {6, 10, 15}), and a geometric parameter (AR = {AR1, AR2, AR3, AR4}). This set of variables gives me a particle position x = x(Q, a, AR) - a function that I am looking for.

My attempt at using the *Enzyme Reaction* function – the only function available in Minitab with three predictors – was unsuccessful. I also tried to do a multiple regression; however, since the result was a linear function, it was neither fit for my experimental results shown below.

[image: My experimental results]

The result of nonlinear regression using the Enzyme Reaction function as well as that of the multiple regression:
[image: My regression results]

Are there any other functions with three predictors that I could use? If I myself needed to define a function, how could I do that? Should I have used another technique?

Any ideas would be highly appreciated.

***UPDATE:***

[Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OEd5MIdk3G_4UWIHgOt1xbXGe7vJjfNl/view?usp=sharing) is my data table. It contains data for a = 10 and 15 um. (Backward and forward flows can be analysed separately.)

EDIT This version of the data may be easier for some readers. I added `_b` and `_f` as suffixes for backward and forward flows. (The column headers are repeated in the spreadsheet.)

```
AR_b a_b Q_b X_b AR_f a_f Q_f X_f
3.5 10  .5  .2986425339 3.5 10  .5  .3438914027
3.5 10   1  .2986425339 3.5 10   1  .3619909502
3.5 10 1.5  .3167420814 3.5 10 1.5  .3800904977
3.5 10   2  .3755656109 3.5 10   2  .4208144796
3.5 10 2.5  .4162895928 3.5 10 2.5  .4524886878
3.5 10   3  .4389140271 3.5 10   3  .5067873303
3.5 10 3.5  .4841628959 3.5 10 3.5  .5429864253
3.5 10   4  .5610859729 3.5 10   4  .5656108597
3.5 10 4.5  .6018099548 3.5 10 4.5  .6380090498
3.5 10   5  .6153846154 3.5 10   5  .6742081448
3.5 10 5.5   .628959276 3.5 10 5.5  .6742081448
3.5 10   6  .6334841629 3.5 10   6  .6787330317
3.5 10 6.5  .6470588235 3.5 10 6.5  .6877828054
3.5 10   7   .665158371 3.5 10   7  .6832579186
3.5 10 7.5  .6696832579 3.5 10 7.5   .665158371
3.5 10   8  .6606334842 3.5 10   8  .6380090498
3.5 10 8.5  .6561085973 3.5 10 8.5  .6153846154
3.5 10   9  .6470588235 3.5 10   9  .6018099548
  4 10  .5  .1990950226   4 10  .5  .2398190045
  4 10   1   .221719457   4 10   1  .2624434389
  4 10 1.5  .2443438914   4 10 1.5  .3438914027
  4 10   2  .2714932127   4 10   2   .371040724
  4 10 2.5  .3031674208   4 10 2.5  .4298642534
  4 10   3  .3529411765   4 10   3   .479638009
  4 10 3.5  .3846153846   4 10 3.5  .4977375566
  4 10   4  .4615384615   4 10   4  .5701357466
  4 10 4.5  .5113122172   4 10 4.5  .6063348416
  4 10   5  .5339366516   4 10   5  .6696832579
  4 10 5.5  .5701357466   4 10 5.5  .6832579186
  4 10   6  .6199095023   4 10   6  .7058823529
  4 10 6.5  .6425339367   4 10 6.5  .7239819005
  4 10   7  .6515837104   4 10   7  .7285067873
  4 10 7.5  .6787330317   4 10 7.5  .7149321267
  4 10   8  .6877828054   4 10   8  .6968325792
  4 10 8.5  .6832579186   4 10 8.5  .6877828054
  4 10   9  .6606334842   4 10   9   .665158371
  5 10  .5  .2669683258   5 10  .5  .1719457014
  5 10   1  .1040723982   5 10   1  .1764705882
  5 10 1.5  .1040723982   5 10 1.5  .2036199095
  5 10   2  .1131221719   5 10   2  .2307692308
  5 10 2.5  .1583710407   5 10 2.5  .2714932127
  5 10   3  .2036199095   5 10   3   .334841629
  5 10 3.5  .2850678733   5 10 3.5  .4117647059
  5 10   4  .3529411765   5 10   4  .4705882353
  5 10 4.5   .407239819   5 10 4.5  .5022624434
  5 10   5   .443438914   5 10   5  .5475113122
  5 10 5.5  .4570135747   5 10 5.5  .5972850679
  5 10   6  .4886877828   5 10   6  .6108597285
  5 10 6.5  .5113122172   5 10 6.5  .6606334842
  5 10   7   .520361991   5 10   7  .6606334842
  5 10 7.5  .5339366516   5 10 7.5  .6787330317
  5 10   8   .556561086   5 10   8  .7104072398
  5 10 8.5  .5656108597   5 10 8.5  .7194570136
  5 10   9  .5746606335   5 10   9  .7149321267
7.5 10  .5  .2533936652 7.5 10  .5  .1719457014
7.5 10   1 .03619909502 7.5 10   1 .08597285068
7.5 10 1.5 .03167420814 7.5 10 1.5  .1040723982
7.5 10   2 .04524886878 7.5 10   2  .1357466063
7.5 10 2.5 .06787330317 7.5 10 2.5  .1945701357
7.5 10   3  .1312217195 7.5 10   3  .2760180995
7.5 10 3.5  .2081447964 7.5 10 3.5  .3529411765
7.5 10   4  .2805429864 7.5 10   4  .4162895928
7.5 10 4.5  .3257918552 7.5 10 4.5  .4705882353
7.5 10   5  .3529411765 7.5 10   5  .5158371041
7.5 10 5.5  .3755656109 7.5 10 5.5  .5475113122
7.5 10   6  .3936651584 7.5 10   6  .5656108597
7.5 10 6.5  .4389140271 7.5 10 6.5  .5746606335
7.5 10   7  .4660633484 7.5 10   7  .6199095023
7.5 10 7.5  .5248868778 7.5 10 7.5   .628959276
7.5 10   8   .556561086 7.5 10   8  .6380090498
7.5 10 8.5  .5656108597 7.5 10 8.5  .6425339367
7.5 10   9  .5746606335 7.5 10   9  .6561085973
3.5 15  .5  .1809954751 3.5 15  .5  .2307692308
3.5 15   1   .185520362 3.5 15   1  .2081447964
3.5 15 1.5  .1900452489 3.5 15 1.5   .221719457
3.5 15   2  .2126696833 3.5 15   2  .2669683258
3.5 15 2.5  .2488687783 3.5 15 2.5  .3393665158
3.5 15   3  .2986425339 3.5 15   3  .3936651584
3.5 15 3.5  .3891402715 3.5 15 3.5  .4570135747
3.5 15   4  .4389140271 3.5 15   4  .5248868778
3.5 15 4.5  .4977375566 3.5 15 4.5  .6380090498
3.5 15   5  .5656108597 3.5 15   5  .7194570136
3.5 15 5.5  .6108597285 3.5 15 5.5  .7556561086
3.5 15   6  .6470588235 3.5 15   6  .7601809955
3.5 15 6.5  .6787330317 3.5 15 6.5  .7556561086
3.5 15   7  .7149321267 3.5 15   7  .7511312217
3.5 15 7.5   .742081448 3.5 15 7.5  .7511312217
3.5 15   8  .7511312217 3.5 15   8  .7466063348
3.5 15 8.5  .7692307692 3.5 15 8.5  .7466063348
3.5 15   9  .7873303167 3.5 15   9  .7466063348
  4 15  .5  .1221719457   4 15  .5   .185520362
  4 15   1  .1040723982   4 15   1  .1990950226
  4 15 1.5  .1221719457   4 15 1.5  .2352941176
  4 15   2  .1447963801   4 15   2  .2533936652
  4 15 2.5   .185520362   4 15 2.5  .3167420814
  4 15   3  .2352941176   4 15   3  .3891402715
  4 15 3.5  .2986425339   4 15 3.5  .4343891403
  4 15   4  .3529411765   4 15   4  .5158371041
  4 15 4.5  .3846153846   4 15 4.5  .5972850679
  4 15   5  .4705882353   4 15   5  .6153846154
```

Comment: Thanks for giving a minus one to my question! Could you at least let me know what is wrong with that?

Comment: Could you post the data? It seems that particle position is sometimes a minimum for $Q \sim$ 1 ml min$^{-1}$ and a maximum for $Q \sim$ 7.5 ml min$^{-1}$  Does either of those indications makes sense in scientific terms? A single functional form may be hide to find here.

Comment: Sure, I'll add it now.

Comment: ... hard to find here.

Comment: I added a Google Drive link to my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is no sense a complete answer, but the graph won't fit in a comment. It's not at all obvious that a single functional form can be found to fit your data, and it's crucial that its analysis is informed by a physical understanding of your system, which you don't explain fully.

Focusing on flow rate alone these scatter plot smooths (no attempt to optimise at all) do hint at turning points in the relationship. If genuine, then it's arguable that no functional form is acceptable that doesn't reproduce them.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Well, I am required by a scientific journal to provide them with an equation. This is why I am trying to find the best x(Q, a, AR). Regardless of how accurate it could be, would you please let me know how I can find the best function for this data set? (Unfortunately, I know almost nothing about statistics).

Comment: I can't add usefully to my comments to date. No physics, no equation suggestion.

Comment: Sorry, but I cannot reveal the physics before I publish my results. I studied statistics a little bit and realised how to define a proper function to fit my data points. However, after trying many different functions, I reached the same point; they can't fit!